# Change Webstorm color scheme and IDE appearance simultaneously

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm

I have developed a habbit of changing between light and dark color schemes and IDE appearance, daily between day light and night time. However it gets really annoyning to have to wait for Webstorm to load it's menus and apply these settings in two separate places (Settings: Appearance and behavior / Editor).

I was wondering if this can be done in a single step, preferably by pressing a button in UI. I hoped macros would have helped me with this task but it seems that macros don't record button presses, so I am unable to record color scheme switching actions. Is there any other solution for this problem? Like a plugin or something... Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `View | Quick Switch Scheme...` menu item (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd>) for faster switching. And when you switch the look and feel to Darcula the editor color scheme should switch automatically to Darcula too. Or do you use a different editor color scheme?

Comment: That's a really nice shortcut. Actualy I use some custom themes I created myself for maximum readability to my own preferrences. So unfortunatelly, it does not change IDE appearance.  EDIT: Wait a sec, I see that there's also a submenu named "Look and feel". From there I can quickly change IDE appearance as desired. Not a 2 in 1 action, but nevertheless, it's fast, and that solves my issue. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, the shortcut is actually with a back tick not a tilde (I fixed my answer).